# How can I make Springboot-annotated classes load properly when they are in a library?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have a working Spring Boot application which includes a class like this:

```
@RestController
@Validated
@RequestMapping("/HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorldController
{
    private static int foo = getFoo ();

    private static int getFoo ()
    {
        System.out.println ("HelloWorldController getFoo");
        return 0;
    }

    public HelloWorldController ()
    {
        System.out.println ("HelloWorldController Constructor");
    }

    @GetMapping("/get")
    public HelloWorld root ()
    {
        return new HelloWorld ("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

The `/get` request is served as expected. When the application starts I can see both `println` outputs.

In a separate project I have a similar class:

```
@RestController
@Validated
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ModularAPIDemoController
{
    private static int foo = getFoo ();

    private static int getFoo ()
    {
        System.out.println ("ModularAPIDemoController getFoo");
        return 0;
    }

    public ModularAPIDemoController ()
    {
        System.out.println ("ModularAPIDemoController Constructor");
    }

    @GetMapping("/get")
    public Message root ()
    {
        return new Message ();
    }
}
```

The second class is built in a `mylib` library using maven and the application `pom.xml` includes it with

```
<dependency>...<artifactId>mylib</artifactId>...</dependency>
```

When the `application.jar` builds I can see `mylib.jar` within `BOOT-INF/lib` however when the service starts I see the `println` from `HelloWorldController` but not from `ModularAPIDemoController`, and the `/api/get` request does not work.

I want a java library which includes `@RequestMapping` annotated classes as well as other Spring annotations such as `@Configuration` and `@EnableWebSecurity` and various other things.

The libraries and applications are being built with Maven. How can I set it up so that Spring loads the annotated classes which are within library dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Add explicitly the packages which are you scanning for this components. Use the annotation `@ComponentScan`  together with the annotation `@SpringBootApplication` so you overwrite the default behavior and add the two package roots like this:

`@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"package1", "package2"})`

Answer (score 0):

In your project you have a class which is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`. By default Spring Boot scans all sub packages (including the package where this class is located) for components (e.g. annotated classes). If your library does not live within some of the sub packages, then you can make it eligible for component scanning by adding the root package of your library in  `@SpringBootApplication`, as [documented](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html)  i.e.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"path.to.your.project.root", "path.to.your.library.root"})
```

This way Spring Boot also scans your library for components. As a consequence of the way how this `@ComponenScan` works, you should put your `@SpringBootApplication`-annotated class in a well defined root package  of your project (e.g. `org.foo.bar`).  Do not put the `@SpringBootApplication`-annotated class into default package since Spring Boot might scan for components from other libraries that you do not want to be scanned.

However, I am not sure if I were putting these classes in a library...

Comment: Thank you, but you lost me a bit at "you should put your @SpringBootApplication-annotated class in a well defined root package of your package which is not the default package" can you clarify please? Much appreciated

Comment: Thank you. I am still trying to get this to work. Perhaps you can help with my [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61456656/how-can-i-make-springbootapplicationscanbasepackages-give-verbose-trace-ou)?