# How can I make @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages...) give verbose trace output?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

The answers to [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61454078/how-can-i-make-springboot-annotated-classes-load-properly-when-they-are-in-a-lib/61454347#61454347) say I should use

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"path.to.your.project.root", "path.to.your.library.root"})
```

to make Spring load components from library jar packages (built with maven).

This looks like it should be the right answer but it isn't working.

Can I tell spring to verbosely print out which paths it is scanning for components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom logging level per packages inside your application.properties or application.yml. Please take a look into the documentation which is here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-custom-log-levels

And you could declare there, for example application.properties

```
logging.level.org.springframework=trace
```

or application.yml:

```
logging:
  level:
    root: ERROR
    org.springframework: TRACE
```

Answer (score 0):

Use log level = `TRACE`

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-logging-format